# Invalid breakdown error in Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm trying to get Insights data where the metric is one event (fb_mobile_activate_app) and the breakdown is done by other event (fb_mobile_first_app_launch). That returns error saying on the one hand my breakdown name is invalid and on the other hand it is on the valid breakdowns list.

I have tried this with all the events fb_* listed in the error message and the result is exactly the same.

Has anyone else seen similar behavior?

```
URL:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/<APP_ID>/app_insights/app_event?event_name=fb_mobile_activate_app&aggregateBy=USERS&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&breakdowns[0]=fb_mobile_first_app_launch


RESPONSE:
{  
   "error":{  
      "message":"(#100) Invalid Breakdown Name: 'fb_mobile_first_launch'. Valid breakdowns for event fb_mobile_first_app_launch are: age, app_version, auth_state, client, country, region_code, city_code, gender, locale, percentile, user_agent, device_model, device_os, carrier, timezone, core_count, screen_dimensions, total_disk_gb, remaining_disk_gb, label_cohort, ui_element, app_name, short_version_code, acquisition_source, acquisition_source_l1, acquisition_source_l2, acquisition_source_l3, fb_mobile_initiated_checkout, fb_mobile_purchase_failed, fb_sp_like_unlike, fb_sp_like_like, fb_sp_share_button_share_click, fb_mobile_purchase, fb_mobile_test, fb_mobile_activate_app, fb_mobile_first_app_launch, fb_sp_share_button_share",
      "type":"OAuthException",
      "code":100
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a API bug. It is now raised and confirmed:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1470043193292603/?search_id